# firing two different events on single action on DOM

Tags: jquery, angularjs

My form has one input element and a button next to it. On input I have ng-blur and on button ng-click. After changing sth in input field, I am directly clicking on button. ng-blur event fires, but ng-click does not. The reason for choosing ng-blur over ng-change is to prevent change firing on every change. What can be done for this?

Comment: Can you should us any code and what do you mean when you say "changing sth in input field".

Comment: It should work, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/yo53u5az/), problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks IIya! To test, I used alert(), rather than console.log()